# brute-force search for correct scalar combination

Tags: python, numpy, sympy

I have the suspicion that a triangle area can be expressed in terms of its edge lengths. (Psst: [Heron's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula).) Given the area `A` and the three edge lengths `a`, `b`, `c`, I would like to brute-force through "combinations" of `a`, `b`, `c` until it matches `A` where "combinations" is a set of predefined operations like `sqrt`, `*`, `+`, `**` etc.

```py
import math

tol = 1.0e-10

t = a + b + c
if abs(A - t) < tol:
    print("got it!")  # no

t = a ** 2
if abs(A - t) < tol:
    print("got it!")  # no

t = math.sqrt(a ** 2 + b)
if abs(A - t) < tol:
    print("got it!")  # no

# ...

t = 0.25 * math.sqrt((a+b+c) * (-a+b+c) * (a-b+c) * (a+b-c))
if abs(A - t) < tol:
    print("got it!")  # YES
```

In a sense, I would like to enumerate all possible formulas from simple to complicated and try them out.

How can I script this? Perhaps [sympy](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/) or [mpmath](https://github.com/fredrik-johansson/mpmath) have helper functions here.

Comment: Do you want something to enumerate possible formulas (brute force) and filter them by the numerical values?

Comment: I assume you can see it should be `if abs(A - t) < tol:`

Comment: I mean, I think that can be solved with a neural network with some log and exponentiation layers (for multiplication/division/powers), and then unravelling the weight matrices, but not sure how to do otherwise considering all the combinations you'll get.  You haven't really defined how generating "all possible formulas"  would work.